# What do I when creating a character and I finished the retop?

Tags: uv, texture-baking, retopology

OK so Ive been working on this project for 1,5 years now and I was finally able to come up with this
[image]

The right one is the sculpted version, the left one is the retopologized version, quad only.
So and now I have no idea what to do next exactly. I first tried to paint the texture on the low poly version, but then I remembered I somehow need all the maps from the sculpted version, and when baking, this happened:

[image]

I added the normal from the sculpted version to the retop-version. I suppose I also did the baking wrong.
When you are at this step at character creation, meaning that you have 2 models, one retopologized and the sculpted one, do you draw the textures on the high poly mesh or bake something else and draw on that?
What would be the next step in a character creating process?

Comment: now you need to bake the normals of the high-poly to the low-poly, and you should not need the high-poly anymore (keep it somewhere though), but it's hard to guess what you've done wrong with the baking, maybe pack your image and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Ok I tried again and it looks better but definetly not like it should https://imgur.com/a/CwB4xZv

Comment: oh, the blend file is too big btw, cant upload it

Comment: or use another plateform and share the link